# How to Switch DBs with Mongoose in NextJS App

Tags: javascript, mongoose, next.js

I'm trying to add db switching into a NextJS app. I'm new to NextJS as a framework but have experience with NodeJS and React. In Node it would be something like this:

```
let db = cache.get(DB_NAME);
const Car = db.model('Car');
let allCars = await Car.find();
```

Where the cached value for DB_NAME is just the cached connection to a specific db. However, I keep getting the error `Schema hasn't been registered for model "Car". Use mongoose.model(name, schema)` even though I created the schema and required it with `require('../models/Car');` in my dbConnection.js file where all of this is taking place. Just because someone will probably ask, here's my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CarSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
... schema stuff...
},
{ timestamps: true });

module.exports = mongoose.models.Car || mongoose.model('Car', CarSchema);
```

Does anyone have any experience with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. As long as you require the models, it's just `db.models.Car` instead of `db.model('Car')`